# How to subset a text by 2 sentences in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(Text = c("This is great. A really great place to be. For sure if you wanna solve R issues. Skilled people.", "Good morning. There are very skilled programmers here. They will help sorting this. I am sure.", "SO is great. You can get many things solve. Additional paragraph."), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I have used to subset the text into sentences:

```
library(textshape)

split_sentence(df$Text)
```

However, I would like to subset the "Text" column every 2 senteces, so to get a list like:

```
This is great.
A really great place to be.
Good morning.
There are very skilled programmers here. 
SO is great.
You can get many things solve.
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split `Text` into separate rows for every sentence and select only 1st 2 sentences in each row. Using `dplyr` you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(Text, sep = '\\.\\s*') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  slice(1:2) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row)

#  Text                                   
#  <chr>                                  
#1 This is great                          
#2 A really great place to be             
#3 Good morning                           
#4 There are very skilled programmers here
#5 SO is great                            
#6 You can get many things solve
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `strsplit` and `head`:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$Text, '(?<=\\.)\\s*', perl = TRUE), head, 2))
# [1] "This is great."                           "A really great place to be."             
# [3] "Good morning."                            "There are very skilled programmers here."
# [5] "SO is great."                             "You can get many things solve."
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution, note this solution allows n to be set as any integer and follows that in a retain / skip pattern.

```
# Number of sentences to keep before removing the same number of sentences: n => integer scalar 
n <- 2

# Split the string into separate sentences: sentences => list of a character vector
res <- subset(data.frame(sentences = unlist(strsplit(paste0(df$Text, collapse = " "), "(?<=\\.)\\s+", perl = TRUE))),
                    ceiling(seq_along(sentences) / n) %% 2 == 1)[ , 1, drop = TRUE]

# Print the result to console: character vector => stdout (console)
res

# Data: 
df = data.frame(Text = c("This is great. A really great place to be. For sure if you wanna solve R issues. Skilled people.", "Good morning. There are very skilled programmers here. They will help sorting this. I am sure.", "SO is great. You can get many things solve. Additional paragraph."), stringsAsFactors = F)
```